# Making triggers in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to triggers and mySQL, and there was a question asked as a part of my class which was to make a trigger that will support inserting a new "invoice" which is apart of the database, and that will automatically update the customer in the 'customer' table by adding this new invoice onto the customer balance attribute.

Sorry if my question isn't clear but I can answer any details that need clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Example of customer, and invoice table as following.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT,
  ...
  transaction_count INT DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE invoice (
  id INT,
  customer_id INT, 
  ...
);
```

And your trigger will be something like this.

```
DELIMITER 
$$
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_counter
AFTER INSERT ON invoice
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO customer
    SET transaction_count = transaction_count + 1
    WHERE id = NEW.customer_id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Following link will be more useful.

[Create Trigger in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx)

When you need to deeper on trigger

[MySQL Trigger Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)